# Partitioning being ignored by SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, partitioning

I've partitioned a huge datatable using HASH method on YEAR('datetimestamp'), with 30 partitions.

However, I noticed that the results were slower than before, instead of faster, when I query something like

```
SELECT * FROM 'mytable' WHERE user_id=100 AND YEAR(datetimestamp) = 2019;
```

Using EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON reveals that it actually seems to be considering the 30 partitions instead of getting just the right ones.

What have I done wrong?

PS - I can get better performance by not doing partitions and instead adding a new INDEX key with (user_id and datetimestamp). My fear is that in a few years the size is so big that having partitions would really help to cut down the query time.

Comment: I just realized that columns used in functions like in my YEAR(date) will not be used for indexes. So I replaced the query with 'date between x and y'. The problem still remains and all partitions are scanned.

Comment: Partitioning by HASH makes no sense in your case. Each record belongs to a random partition, so all partitions are processed. And use the expression in a query which is equal to partitioning one - i.e. either partitioning by `YEAR(datetimestamp)` or selecting by `datetimestamp between x and y`.

Comment: @Akina, what do you mean each record belongs to a random partition? The hash function uses YEAR(date) as the argument, so rows with the same year should belong to the same partition.

Comment: Maybe I have used a wrong words... sorry, I'll try to re-explain. I mean that HASH obtained from the value is close to random (the only difference - it is deterministic). So while looking at the record it is practically impossible to predict without hash calculation in what partition the record will be saved. So the records which are visually from the same date range in practice occurs in all partitions in approximately equal amount. I.e. partitioning achieves nothing. And that's why SELECT "ignores" it. You need partition BY RANGE, not BY HASH..

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, `PARTITION BY HASH` provides no performance benefits.  Or any other kind of benefit I have found.  And, as you have found, `HASH` tends to look at *all* partitions.

So, what do do instead?  For this:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable`
    WHERE user_id = 100
      AND YEAR(datetimestamp) = 2019;
```

do:

- No partitioning;
- Change the `YEAR` test to

  ```
  AND datetimestamp >= '2019-01-01'
  AND datetimestamp  < '2019-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
  ```
- And have

  ```
  INDEX(user_id, datetimestamp)
  ```

That way, it will do a simple range scan on the index.

`YEAR(...)` is not "sargeable", but my formulation above is.

Comment: thanks. I've also found that testing the timestamp in that manner has better results. Still, why not use that AND partitioning since the total nr of rows to scan will be much less?

Comment: @NunoDonato - Without partitioning, one table is checked for the rows needed, and the scan of the index is a single contiguous part of the index that I suggested.  With partitioning, especially `BY HASH`, all partitions need to be opened and checked for rows to deliver.  (Each "partition" is effectively a separate "table".)